# select multiple cities suggested by google places

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, google-places-api, v-select

i'm using v-select and i'm trying to have a multiple select through which to select one or more cities, suggested by google ... does anyone know if it can be done?
I don't even find examples
https://vue-select.org/

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at their sandbox's link https://vue-select.org/sandbox.html

You can enable the  :multiple="true" checkbox on the side menu.
It will show that multiple select is possible.
[image]